# Why can't I chain String.replace?

Tags: elixir

I'm working on a price format function, which takes a float, and represent it properly.

ex. 190.5, should be 190,50

This is what i came up with

```
  def format_price(price) do
    price
    |> to_string
    |> String.replace ".", ","
    |> String.replace ~r/,(\d)$/, ",\\1 0"
    |> String.replace " ", ""
  end
```

If i run the following.

```
format_price(299.0)
# -> 299,0
```

It looks like it only ran through the first replace. Now if i change this to the following.

```
  def format_price(price) do
    formatted = price
    |> to_string
    |> String.replace ".", ","

    formatted = formatted
    |> String.replace ~r/,(\d)$/, ",\\1 0"

    formatted = formatted
    |> String.replace " ", ""
  end
```

Then everything seems to work just fine.

```
format_price(299.0)
# -> 299,00
```

Why is this?

Comment: In general (for those who may read this later) when you're piping arguments through functions, make sure you put parentheses around your arguments.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**EDIT** On the master branch of Elixir, the compiler will warn if a function is piped into without parentheses if there are arguments.

---

This is an issue of precedence that can be fixed with explicit brackets:

```
price
|> to_string
|> String.replace(".", ",")
|> String.replace(~r/,(\d)$/, ",\\1 0")
|> String.replace(" ", "")
```

Because function calls have a higher precedence than the `|>` operator your code is the same as:

```
price
|> to_string
|> String.replace(".",
  ("," |> String.replace ~r/,(\d)$/,
    (",\\1 0" |> String.replace " ", "")))
```

Which if we substitute the last clause:

```
price
|> to_string
|> String.replace(".",
  ("," |> String.replace ~r/,(\d)$/, ".\\10"))
```

And again:

```
price
|> to_string
|> String.replace(".", ",")
```

Should explain why you get that result.

Comment: @Gazler, do you have a link to the commit that introduces the change?

Comment: @asymmetric https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/3487d00ddb5e90c7cf0e65d03717903b9b27eafd