# Halt a connection after a redirect

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Inside a controller, I'm checking the session of the connection to verify if the session is attached to a user. If not, I redirect it to an other page.

**But** the `halt` returns me an error if I try to call it after the redirect:

> no function clause matching in Plug.Conn.halt/1

And without the `halt` the page of the original controller does a render and print an error in the console (the template is rendered without a user):

> (exit) an exception was raised: (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: nil.username/0

**So my question is**: is it possible to call the `halt` after a redirect ?

- If yes, which part of my code is wrong ?
- If no, how can I prevent the controller to render the page ?

Here's the code of my controller and the module used in it.

```
defmodule Mccm.DashboardController do
  use Mccm.Web, :controller

  import Mccm.Plug.Session
  import Mccm.Session, only: [current_user: 1]

  plug :needs_to_be_logged_in

  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> render "index.html", user: current_user(conn)
  end
end
```

---

```
defmodule Mccm.Plug.Session do
  import Mccm.Session, only: [logged_in?: 1, is_teacher?: 1]
  import Phoenix.Controller, only: [redirect: 2]
  import Plug.Conn, only: [halt: 1]

  def needs_to_be_logged_in(conn, _) do
    if !logged_in?(conn) do
      conn
      |> redirect to: "/"
      |> halt # this give me an error
    else
      conn
    end
  end
end
```

Here's dependencies used:

- phoenix: 1.0.2
- phoenix_ecto: 1.1
- phoenix_html: 2.1
- cowboy: 1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** On the master branch of Elixir, the compiler will warn if a function is piped into without parentheses if there are arguments.

---

Try doing:

```
  def needs_to_be_logged_in(conn, _) do
    if !logged_in?(conn) do
      conn
      |> redirect(to: "/") # notice the brackets
      |> halt # this give me an error
    else
      conn
    end
  end
```

Your code was doing:

```
|> redirect(to: "/", |> halt)
```

And the error correctly identified that there is no pattern for:

```
halt(to: "/")
```

See [Why Can't I Chain String.replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615447/why-cant-i-chain-string-replace) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: This resolve my issue and I wonder why I didn't think about that. Thank you for your answer!