# elixir piping, can pipe if new variable, can't pipe if sending directly to pipe, why?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a nested model and wanted to do some basic piping. My end goal is to remove any nested map where `id == ""` for the below params:

`params = %{"name" => "OuterModelName", "InnerModel" => %{"0" => %{"id" => "2"}, "1" => %{"id" => "3"}, "2" => %{"id" => ""}}}`

To remove the `id ==""` the following pipe works:

```
blanksRemoved = 
        params 
        |> Map.update! "InnerModel", fn(innerMap) -> 
            Enum.filter(innerMap,fn{k,v} -> byte_size(v["id"]) !=0 end) end
```

blanksRemoved is now:

`%{"name" => "OuterModelName", "InnerModel" => [{"0", %{"id" => "2"}}, {"1", %{"id" => "3"}}]}`

Notice the innerModel became an array so I need to turn that array back into a struct.

```
asStruct = 
      blanksRemoved |> Map.update! "InnerModel", fn(innerMap) -> 
            Enum.into(innerMap,%{}) end
```

And that works as intended and I get:

`%{"name" => "OuterModelName", "InnerModel" => %{"0" => %{"id" => "2"}, "1" => %{"id" => "3"}}}`

However when I try simply combining the two pipes with the below pipe, , I get an error.

```
combinedPipes = 
        params 
        |> Map.update! "InnerModel", fn(innerMap) -> 
            Enum.filter(innerMap,fn{k,v} -> byte_size(v["id"]) !=0 end) end
        |> Map.update! "InnerModel", fn(innerMap) -> 
            Enum.into(innerMap,%{}) end
```

And the error:

```
argument error
    (stdlib) :maps.find("InnerModel", #Function<2.64012156
```

I know the error is because it can't find "InnerModel" but I don't know why it can't find that when it's working when I separate the pipes. Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: keep in mind that `[{"0", %{"id" => "2"}}, {"1", %{"id" => "3"}}]` denotes a list, not an array; the difference is not trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** On the master branch of Elixir, the compiler will warn if a function is piped into without parentheses if there are arguments.

---

You need explicit parenthesis around your function calls as the function call has a higher precedence than the pipe operator.

```
combinedPipes = 
        params 
        |> Map.update!("InnerModel", fn(innerMap) -> 
            Enum.filter(innerMap,fn{k,v} -> byte_size(v["id"]) !=0 end) end)
        |> Map.update!("InnerModel", fn(innerMap) -> 
            Enum.into(innerMap,%{}) end)
```

You can read a more detailed explanation at [Why Can't I Chain String.replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615447/why-cant-i-chain-string-replace/32615517#32615517)

Comment: Man this is another Elixir FAQ. :)