# Using pipe with filter and map in elixir

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I am attempting to filter out some values from a map in Elixir.

This:

```
params = %{"blah" => "blah", "vtha" => "blah"}
params 
  |>  Enum.filter fn {k, v} -> k == v end 
  |>  Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> {k, v} end)
```

Result in this Error:
     ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Enumerable.Function.reduce/3

But both the filter and map operations work in isolation.

```
Enum.filter params, fn {k, v} -> k == v end 
Enum.map(params, fn {k, v} -> {k, v} end)
```

They don't work when piped.

I am sure I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT** On the master branch of Elixir, the compiler will warn if a function is piped into without parentheses if there are arguments.

---

You need explicit parenthesis for `Enum.filter` as the function call has a stronger precedence than the pipe operator.

```
params = %{"blah" => "blah", "vtha" => "blah"}
params 
  |>  Enum.filter(fn {k, v} -> k == v end)
  |>  Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> {k, v} end)
```

Please see [Why Can't I Chain String.replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615447/why-cant-i-chain-string-replace) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be something obvious. :)