# Printing a Stream in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm playing with Elixir, and I stumbled upon something that confuses me.

I defined this anonymous function, which matches against strings starting with a digit:

```
digits = &(&1 =~ ~r/^\d/)
```

If I try to use this function in a `Stream.reject/2`, and then print the contents of the `Stream`, I get an error:

```
File.stream!("foobar") |> Stream.reject digits |> Enum.to_list

** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Enumerable.Function.reduce/3
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:2641: Enumerable.Function.reduce(#Function<6.54118792/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>, {:cont, []}, #Function<7.8839654/2 in Enum.reduce/3>)
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1400: Enum.reduce/3
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:2130: Enum.to_list/1
```

And again:

```
File.stream!("foobar") |> Stream.reject digits |> Enum.each &IO.write/1

** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Enumerable.Function.reduce/3
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:2641: Enumerable.Function.reduce(#Function<6.54118792/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>, {:cont, nil}, #Function<7.8839654/2 in Enum.reduce/3>)
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1400: Enum.reduce/3
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:584: Enum.each/2
```

It seems that in the former case, the `{ :cont, []}` tuple is creating problems, and in the latter, it's `{ :cont, nil }`, but I could find no mention of these tuples in the docs.

Interestingly, the above works if I use an `Enum` instead of a `Stream`

```
File.stream!("foobar")  |> Enum.reject digits
[ "nice", "list" ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need explicit parentheses for your `Stream.reject` function. See [Why Can't I Chain String.replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615447/why-cant-i-chain-string-replace) for a detailed explanation.

```
File.stream!("foobar") |> Stream.reject(digits) |> Enum.each(&IO.write/1)
```