# How to pipe Enum output to another Enum function that takes multiple arguments?

Tags: elixir

I'm just learning Elixir and I'm trying to do this:

```
list = Enum.with_index ~w[a n b e c r z b d]

#=> [{"a", 0}, {"n", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"e", 3}, {"c", 4}, {"r", 5}, {"z", 6}, {"b", 7},
 {"d", 8}]

Enum.into(list, %{})

#=> %{"a" => 0, "b" => 7, "c" => 4, "d" => 8, "e" => 3, "n" => 1, "r" => 5,
  "z" => 6}
```

I'd like to do it as a pipe... something like:

```
Enum.with_index ~w[a n b e c r z b d] |> Enum.into(%{})
```

or

```
Enum.with_index ~w[a n b e c r z b d] |> Enum.into(&1, %{})
```

But neither of those work. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parentheses:

```
Enum.with_index(~w[a n b e c r z b d]) |> Enum.into(%{})
```

Or more idiomatically:

```
~w[a n b e c r z b d] |> Enum.with_index() |> Enum.into(%{})
```

Your original version would be executed as:

```
Enum.with_index(~w[a n b e c r z b d] |> Enum.into(%{}))
```

You can see [Why Can't I Chain String.replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615447/why-cant-i-chain-string-replace/32615517#32615517) for a detailed explanation of this.